Questions regarding a P-Norm of a Derivative
If I understand correctly, the definition of $p$-norm is as follows,
$$
\|\mathbf{x}\|_p := \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}.
$$
Considering that $p = 2$ and if I have $\mathbf{x}$ as $\mathbf{D}x$, where $\mathbf{D}$ is the derivative operator, how should I proceed then? Should I go with $\mathbf{D}x \cdot \mathbf{D}x$ or $\mathbf{D}^2 x$? Because I currently have an equation of this form,
$$
\|\mathbf{D}x - \mathbf{D}y\|_2^2 = 0
$$
and I want to solve for $y$. I am not sure whether I should take the square of the differentiated variables or take the derivative twice.

Why does $y=x$ not work for you?

Since the $p$-norm is a norm, $\Vert \mathbf{D} x - \mathbf{D} y \Vert_2^2 = 0$ implies that $\mathbf{D} x = \mathbf{D} y$. So if you are solving for $y$, the solution is $y = x + c$, where $\mathbf{D}c = 0$.

This indeed works. But I am more interested in which approach should I proceed with. Will it be the square of the differentiated variable or just take the derivative twice.
